# How to infer the right types of component's @Input

Tags: angular, typescript, strong-typing

I'm looking for a way to infer the right types of a component's @Inputs.
So far, I'm only able to target the `@Input` properties using the following:

```
// Method in a service
setComponentInputs<T> (props: { [key in keyof T]?: any }) {
   console.log(props);
}
```

But as you can see the type is still `any`
Also, the current approach allows to target everything within the Component, including methods (e.g OnInit), but I'm not so sure if there's is a trick to target only the @Inputs.

Let me provide you with more context, this is a standard Angular Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: '',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss']
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() myProp: string;
  @Input() otherProp: CustomProp;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

The idea is to call `setComponentInputs(props)` while restricting the props argument to match the component `@Inputs` properties

```
// this one should compile
myService.setComponentInputs<FooComponent>({myProp: 'Hello there!'});

// this one should raise an error (because the type of myProp is string)
myService.setComponentInputs<FooComponent>({myProp: 123});

// this one should raise an error (because the referenced property don't even exist)
myService.setComponentInputs<FooComponent>({newProp: 'Hello!'});
```

**Edit 1:** I've found a way to overcome the main issue using *Mapped Types*

```
// Method in a service
setComponentInputs<T> (props: { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] }) {
   console.log(props);
}
```

But then @andrei pointed out a different and easier approach:

```
// Method in a service
setComponentInputs<T> (props: Partial<T>) {
   console.log(props);
}
```

The remaining piece will be how to allow only the properties while excluding Functions (e.g OnInit)

```
// this one should raise an error (because ngOnInit is a Function)
myService.setComponentInputs<FooComponent>({ngOnInit: () => {});
```

Comment: will `setComponentInputs<T>(props: Partial<T>) ...` work for you? see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html for more information

Comment: Actually, it does!  I was able to solve it by using `props: { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] }` but your approach is cleaner. Thanks for the cool breeze!

Comment: There's still one problem... Even with your solution or mine, I can still access the Functions (e.g NgOnInit) ideally I should be able to set only properties.

Comment: try this: `props: { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Function ? never : T[P] }`

Comment: @Andrei, that's genius! Works like a charm :)

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems like { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Function ? never : T[P] } can be translated into Exclude<Partial<T>, Function>

Comment: nah, that is not the same. Exclude  excludes some types from union, and won't work for some object values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution based on Andrei's feedback.

```
// Method in a service
setComponentInputs<T> (props: { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Function ? never : T[P] }) {
   console.log(props);
}
```

Next step would be to create a generic type and use it where needed.
Thanks @andrei :)

Answer (score 0):

In a Input you can use "coerce", see [this entry from Tomasz Kula](https://netbasal.com/trust-but-verify-coerce-your-component-inputs-bdb743e8b579), e.g.

```
private _value: number;
get value(): number {
  return this._value;
}
@Input()
set value(value: number) {
  this._value = coerceNumberProperty(value, 0);
}
```

when define a function you can indicate the type

```
setComponentInput(value:{'myProp':string}){}
```