# Infer component @Input() properties' types

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to write a helper service to handle modals. Let's say we have a service `ModalService` that has an `open` method, and an Angular component called `ConfirmationModal`:

```js
@Component({
  template: `<p>{{ message }}</p>`,
  standalone: true
})
export class ConfirmationModal {

  // I want only the 'message' property to be present in the type-hinted
  // object as the type of the second argument when ConfirmationModal is passed to
  // the ModalService.open() method as the first argument
  @Input() public message = 'Do you confirm this action?';

  @Output() public cancel = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() public confirm = new EventEmitter();

}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ModalService {

  constructor(protected ngbModal: NgbModal) { }

  // By passing the component type I want the second argument to
  // be the type containing the @Input() properties of that component
  public open<TComponent>(
    componentClass: Type<TComponent>,
    options: ???
  ) {
    const modal = this.ngbModal.open(componentClass);

    // Initialize component's @Input() properties
    if (options) {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(options)) {
        modal.componentInstance[key] = value;
      }
    }

    return modal;
  }

}
```

So the result I want to achieve is that when you type this:

```
modalService.open(ConfirmationModal, { ... });
```

The second argument should be an object containing the @Input() properties of the modal component, so it should only allow an object like `{ message: 'Some string here' }`. The IDE should type-hint only the `message` key and neither `cancel` nor `confirm`. Similar question ([How to infer the right types of component's @Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925701/how-to-infer-the-right-types-of-components-input)) was given an answer that could exclude function like `ngOnInit`.

The best I could come up with is to create some helpers:

```js
// Helper type that makes the type inference work
export interface IModal<TOptions> {
  // The generic type has to be used for the inference to work properly
  // The drawback is that it has to be declared in the modal component
  _options?: TOptions;
}

// This represents the available options for a modal that
// will be passed as component inputs in ModalService.open()
export interface IConfirmationModal {
  message?: string;
}

// Helper type that infers the generic type of a component
// Example: TModalOptions<ConfirmationModal> = IConfirmationModal
type TModalOptions<T> = T extends IModal<infer K> ? K : {};
```

...and use them like that:

```js
export class ConfirmationModal implements IModal<IConfirmationModal> {

  /* ... */

  // Had to be placed here because of the implementing interface
  public _options?: IConfirmationModal;

}

export class ModalService {

  // ...

  public open<TComponent>(
    componentClass: Type<TComponent>,
    options?: TModalOptions<TComponent>
  ) { /* ... */ }

}
```

This gives the desired result. But the question is can we do something to at least get rid of the `public _options?: IConfirmationModal;` line as it may sem confusing to other developers and just seems off. For some reason this trick doesn't work without it.

Another approach would be to declare functions for every modal in the service, but I want to dodge it. I could look something like that:

```js
export class ModalService {

  // ...

  public openConfirmation(
    componentClass: Type<ConfirmationModal>,
    options: IConfirmationModal)
  { /* ... */ }

}
```

Code for reference:

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Injectable, Input, Output, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  template: `<button (click)="openModal()">Open modal</button>`,
  standalone: true
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(protected modalService: ModalService) { }

  public openModal() {
    // I want the second argument to be inferred as IConfirmationModal,
    // because i passed ConfirmationModal as the first argument
    this.modalService.open(ConfirmationModal, { message: 'Custom confirmation message' });
  }

}

// Helper type that makes the type inference work
export interface IModal<TOptions> {
  // The generic type has to be used for the inference to work properly
  // The drawback is that it has to be declared in the modal component
  _options?: TOptions;
}

// This represents the available options for a modal that
// will be passed as component inputs in ModalService.open()
export interface IConfirmationModal {
  message?: string;
}

// Helper type that infers the generic type of a component
// Example: TModalOptions<ConfirmationModal> = IConfirmationModal
type TModalOptions<T> = T extends IModal<infer K> ? K : {};

@Component({
  template: `<p>{{ message }}</p>`,
  standalone: true
})
export class ConfirmationModal implements IModal<IConfirmationModal> {

  // I want only the 'message' property to be present in the type-hinted
  // object as the type of the second argument when ConfirmationModal is passed to
  // the ModalService.open() method as the first argument
  @Input() public message = 'Do you confirm this action?';

  @Output() public cancel = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() public confirm = new EventEmitter();

  // Had to be placed here because of the implementing interface
  public _options?: IConfirmationModal;

}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ModalService {

  constructor(protected ngbModal: NgbModal) { }

  // By passing the component type I want the second argument to
  // be the type containing the @Input() properties of that component
  public open<TComponent>(
    componentClass: Type<TComponent>,
    options?: TModalOptions<TComponent>
  ) {
    const modal = this.ngbModal.open(componentClass);

    // Initialize component's @Input() properties
    if (options) {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(options)) {
        modal.componentInstance[key] = value;
      }
    }

    return modal;
  }

}
```